# What is this for loop doing? I don't understand the functionality of the for loop here

Tags: arrays, c, boolean, primes

This is my code to print all the prime numbers between 1 to 100; I need to use arrays for this and this is important part of the challenge:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int p;
    int i;

    int primes[50] = {0};
    int primeIndex = 2;

    bool isPrime;

    // hardcode prime numbers
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;

    for(p = 5; p <= 100; p = p + 2)
    {
        isPrime = true;

        for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
            if (p % primes[i] == 0)
                isPrime = false;

        if (isPrime == true)
        {
            primes[primeIndex] = p;
            ++primeIndex;
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0;  i < primeIndex;  ++i )
         printf ("%i  ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For the most part, I do understand the code but I can't understand this part of the code:

```
for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
```

Particularly, the termination condition of the for loop – `isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]`. Can you please help me out here? I am a beginner when it comes to the C language.

Comment: This condition tells you that the loop will continue as long as ```isPrime == true``` and ```p``` divided by ```primes[i]``` is greater than ```primes[i]``` in other word ```p``` must be greater than ```primes[i]^2```

Answer (score 0):

1. `isPrime` is a flag indicating that the number is potentially prime (ie we do not proved opposite)
2. `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]` checks if it makes sense to check if the number is prime for the previously found prime as a divisor
3. `p % primes[i] == 0` checks if the number is not prime - setting the flag from point 1.